# How to differentiate from the server side, between the first request of the browser (HTML file) and the following (images, CSS, scripts...)?

Tags: mod-rewrite, browser, request

I'm programming a website with SEO friendly links, ie, put the page title or other descriptive text in the link, separated by slashes. For example: **h*tp://www.domain.com/section/page-title-bla-bla-bla/**.

I redirect the request to the main script with mod_rewrite, but links in **script**, **img** and **link** tags are not resolved correctly. For example: assuming you are visiting the above link, the tag  request the file at the URL **h*tp://www.domain.com/section/page-title-bla-bla-bla/js/file.js**, but the file is actually **http://www.domain.com/js/file.js**

I do not want to use a variable or constant in all HTML file URLs.

I'm trying to redirect client requests to a directory or to another of the server. It is possible to distinguish the first request for a page, which comes after? It is possible to do with mod_rewrite for Apache, or PHP?

I hope I explained well:)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe, but what  do you need this for in the first place? There may be an easier way for whatever you want to do.

Comment: I edited my question with a better explanation

Comment: You should cure the cause instead of fixing the symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rewrite rules to fix the problem of relative paths is unwise and has numberous downsides.

Firstly, it makes things more difficult to maintain because there are hundreds of different links in your system.

Secondly and more seriously, you destroy cacheability. A resource requested from here:

```
http://www.domain.com/section/page-title-bla-bla-bla/js/file.js
```

will be regarded as a different resource from

```
http://www.domain.com/section/some-other-page-title/js/file.js
```

and loaded two times, causing the number of requests to grow dozenfold.

**What to do?**

Fix the root cause of the problem instead: Use absolute paths

```
<script src="/js/file.js">
```

or a constant, or if all else fails the `<base>` tag.

Comment: I can't use absolute paths because the base URL can contain directories (`http://domain.com/dir/dir/`). But I can use the `<base>` tag. It's fantastic!

Thanks for your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of [resolving relative URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5). Judging by your description, it seems that you reference the other resources using relative URI paths: In `/section/page-title-bla-bla-bla` a URI reference like `js/file.js` or `./js/file.js` would be resolved to `/section/page-title-bla-bla-bla/js/file.js`.

To always reference `/js/file.js` independet from the actual base URI path, use the absolute path `/js/file.js`. Another solution would be to set the base URI explicitly to `/` using the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) (but note that this will affect *all* relative URIs).

Comment: Thank you very much !! I think the `<base>` tag is the solution.

Comment: @Efrain Yoel: Be aware that changing the base URI path will affect all relative URIs that don’t specify a path (including relative URIs like `?foo` and `#bar`).